# Can I have optional properties in a GAE datastore model?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, geospatial, option-type

I have a GAE application, where I'm using the [geomodel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/) for a location based model in my database. There are two "types" of this model, however, they need to be geo-queryed together as one. The two "types" share a set of base properties, but the second type has a few more. Is there any way I can make those other properties optional rather than just setting them to bogus values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the datastore, entities are independent of each other.  You can have different entities of the same Kind that have different sets of attributes.  This happens very commonly if you add some new attributes on a new version of your app, and the entities that already exist in the datastore won't have those attributes.

In your code though, for any given version you end up declaring a single Model for your Kind.  You can choose not to assign values to certain attributes for the different types.

Simply make sure that your code properly handles cases where attributes don't exist, or are set to None.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I ended up doing.